# Can Anyone Create Cookie from their computer for my website?

Tags: php, cookies, dns, set

I am creating a website which requires user login and I uses only one cookie to set user logged in. Is it Secure??

One can Delete Cookies with firebug So can user create a cookie for my website with any softwares and make my code fool??

Please reply if They can How to stop them from doing that??

Comment: Yes they can create their own cookie, no it isn't secure.... use sessions, not cookies, for login

Comment: So Sessions are Secure Enough?? Aren't they created in tmp folder??

Comment: Cookies are not secure. They should only be used for the convenience of the client by remembering their usernames and/or passwords for them. They should not be used to check if they are logged in. Like @Mark_Baker said, you should use sessions instead. Try looking into form authentication and using Jsessions. That's at least a start. =)

Comment: Session files are created in the /tmp folder by default; that can be changed (depending on your hosting); but it shouldn't be any folder that's publicly accessible

Comment: you mean tmp folder on my server?? if you mean that how the server handels toooo many sessions at a time??

Comment: @Brian: Do not store a password in a cookie.  Ever.

Comment: Yes, I mean the /tmp folder on the server: cookies are client-side (so the client can manipulate them); session files are server-side, where the client can't access them

Comment: @SLaks: Many websites use cookies to store passwords. I stated that cookies are not secure, but they are still used by many applications to remember your password. Is it safe? No. But it is convenient for the client and it is still something that many applications use.

Comment: @Brian: No.  No secure or respectable website will store a password in a cookie.  "Remember me" features are either implemented in the browser (using actual security) or simply use a signed token.

Comment: @SLacks: I see. I suppose I should have been more blunt about cookies not being secure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Cookies come from the **client**.

A malicious client can send any data it likes, whether in cookies, URLs, or POST payloads.

---

If you want to prevent that, you can cryptographically sign your cookies using a secret key that only resides on the server.
This way, a malicious client cannot sign any fake cookies.

You will still need to prevent replay attacks.

Comment: can you please Explain what is that "cryptographically sign"??

Comment: @NijrajGelani: You should start searching for articles that explain this in detail, otherwise this discussion will go on forever.

Comment: You need to learn far more about cryptography before you actually do that.